# How deadlock can occur if one query waits for the lock held by other query

Tags: mysql, concurrency

I am facing following exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

What I can tell is that I have multiple threads executing queries on same tables in parallel. But I can't understand why this exception can occur. Since if one query has locked a table, then the same query(or other query on the same table) in another thread will wait for the lock. How come the deadlock is created?

I repeat in different words, I understand the exception, but what I don't understand is that a query is waiting for other query, the other query should execute, leave the lock, and waiting query can acquire the lock, why deadlock?

If someone wants to look the actual queries(These queries are executed in multiple threads in the same order as printed here, **without any transactions**):

```
UPDATE daily_stats, account, campaign SET campaign_messages_cost = campaign_messages_cost + (IF(current_free_sms >= ?, campaign.campaign_cost, campaign.campaign_cost + (account.sms_charging_rate * ? ))), campaign_messages_delivered_count = campaign_messages_delivered_count + 1 WHERE daily_stats_id = ? AND campaign.id = ? AND daily_stats.account_id = account.id

update account a JOIN campaign b ON a.id = b.account_id set campaign_cost = IF(current_free_sms >= ?, campaign_cost, campaign_cost + (a.sms_charging_rate * ? )), delivered_count = delivered_count + ?, credit = IF(current_free_sms >= ?, credit, credit - (a.sms_charging_rate * ?)), current_free_sms = IF (current_free_sms >= ?, current_free_sms - ?, current_free_sms) where b.id = ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL regards any query statement as a transaction (at least when using the default InnoDB engine) but if the @@autocommit variable is set to 1 (default) all statements are immediately autocommited, effectively hiding that a transaction took place. This can explain the "deadlock found" error despite no begin/commit/rollback, although the "rollback" part of the error message is both somewhat mysterious and nothing I have seen before.

MySQLs proposed way of handling deadlocks is a combination of structuring your queries to minimize the problem, and in addition to write code which handles them when they do occur – because they will in software like yours. My way around is simple but efficient: sleep for 500 msec and retry. I have very seldom seen more than two consecutive retries, on a system which handles fairly high loads (though in a corporate environment).

You should also check out [MySQLs recommendations on how to cope with deadlocks.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-deadlocks.html)